# Check whether my proof is correct or not.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

**The problem is** :

> If the series $\sum a_n ^2$ and $\sum b_n ^2$ be both convergent, prove that the series $\sum a_n b_n$ is absolutely convergent.

Using A.M. > G.M. we have $(a_n ^2 + b_n ^2)/2 \geq |a_n b_n|$.From here the required result can be easily proved with the help of comparison test.

Is it ok or are their alternative ways?Please help me.Thank you in advance.

Comment: I feel like alternative ways would end up using or being equivalent to AMGM to be honest. This looks fine to me.

Comment: You may also have to state that if $\sum a_n ^2$ and $\sum b_n ^2$ are both convergent then so is $\sum a_n ^2+ b_n ^2$

Comment: Yeah since it is obvious I left it.

Comment: This is correct; one could also have done with Cauchy-Schwarz instead of AM-GM, but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: Or more basic, and underlying many proofs of AM/GM and CS: $(x-y)^2\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left|a_n b_n\right|\leq \min\left(\sqrt{\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n^2\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}b_n^2\right)},\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}(a_n^2+b_n^2)\right)$$
so the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality always give a better bound than AM-GM or $(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2\geq 0$, but both ways are just fine to prove the statement.